# Suppose $M$ is free $R/\text{Ann}(m)$-module of rank $h$. Is $M$ a cyclic $R/\text{Ann}(m)$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a DVR. If $M$ is a cyclic $R$-module, then by definition, $M$ is generated by a single element say $m \in M$ i.e., $M=Rm$.  Since $M$ is generated by a single element $m \in M$, we must have an epimorphism $$ f: R \to M, ~~f(r)=rm, ~\ r \in R,$$ where $\text{Ker}(f)=\{r \in R: rm=0\}:=\text{Ann}(m).$ Thus by 1st isomorphism theorem of ring, we have $$M \cong R/\text{Ann}(m)~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
Also we know that for any ideal $I$ of $R$, then $R/I$ is a cyclic $R$-module.

Therefore if the relation $(1)$ holds, then we can say $M$ is cyclic $R$-module.

Am I right so far ?

**Question:**

Suppose $M$ is free $R/\text{Ann}(m)$-module of rank $h$. Is $M$ a cyclic $R$-module ? Is $M$ a cyclic $R/\text{Ann}(m)$-module ? If not, what assumption makes the answer yes ?

---

If $h=1$, then  looking at the relation $(1)$, $M$ is cyclic $R$-module. Also, since $M$ is torsion free  $R/\text{Ann}(m)$-module of rank $1$, it is cyclic.

I need help when $h>1$.

Thanks

Comment: If $R$ is a field and $M$ is any $R$-module, then $Ann(m) = 0$ for every $m \in M$. Therefore every $R$-module is a free $R/Ann(m)$-module and your hypothesis yields no information about $M$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thanks. But if $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is cyclic $R$-module

Comment: Yes. As you say in your post, an $R$-module $M$ is cyclic iff it is congruent to $R/I$ for some ideal $I$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, so according your last comment, an $R$-module $M$ is cyclic if it is congruent to $R/\text{Ann}(m)$ for some $m \in M$. Is it ?

Comment: Yes, and you proved this correctly in your post! Also note that  a DVR is a principal ideal domain so in your case $Ann(m)$ is principally generated and the cyclic modules are, up to isomorphism, $R/rR$ for $r \in R$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, Thanks for nice comment